# "<FlexLexer.h> not found", only happens in C++ mode

Tags: android, c++, flex-lexer, file-not-found

I am testing and playing a bit with flex before I start using it for a real project, but I am facing sone issues.

I am working on Android using a Linux emulator named Termux. I've installed flex and clang executing respectively `$ apt install flex` and `$ apt install clang`.

I have noticed that if I write flex code for C, process it with `$ flex filename`, and then compile it with `$ gcc -lfl lex.yy.c`, everything compiles and the binary works perfectly.

But if I write flex code for C++ (i.e. using C++ only features), process it with `$ flex -+ filename` and compile it with `$ g++ -lfl lex.yy.cc`, during compilation an error pops out saying that a file `FlexLexer.h`, included as

```
#include <FlexLexer.h>
```

was not found.

Why does this only happen when using C++? Since I actually need it for C++, how can I fix this issue, minding that I am working on Android using an emulator?

Comment: Where is the FlexLexer.h present? Which directory??

Comment: @Techidiot I don't really know. As I said, I installed it with `$ apt install flex`, and so it's probably in a directory I can't normally access like `/data`.

Comment: You should always put `-l` options *after* the file which references the library: `gcc lex.yy.c -lfl` or `g++ lex.yy.cc -lfl`. I'd recommend always using `-Wall` as well, and specifying an explicit output file with `-o executable-name` rather than letting the executable be put into `a.out`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in the `flex` package in Termux and has now been fixed - run `apt update && apt upgrade` to get the updated package which contains `FlexLexer.h`.

Comment: I never expected the actual creator to anser my question. Thanks a lot! Why isn't there a `termux` tag anyway?

Answer (score 3):

On some versions of Debian/Ubuntu (such as Ubuntu 18.04 "Bionic") you may need to install the `fl-dev` package to get the `FlexLexer.h` header file. You can always check what package provides a file using the search tool at https://packages.ubuntu.com/

`sudo apt install libfl-dev`